# How do I put the vertical text Advertisement to the right of AdSense Ads?

Tags: css, adsense, vertical-text

From Google Adsense at https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/4533986?hl=en

Labeling ads

Publishers have two options for how to label AdSense ad units: You can either label the units with "Advertisements" or "Sponsored Links". No other variations are allowed at this time.

How do I create CSS for this?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. Does anyone see a problem or offer a better solution?

For horizontal ads, wrap your ad with a div

```
<div class="adHorizontal">
```

And use this CSS:

```
div.adHorizontal ins.adsbygoogle:before {
content: 'Advertisement';
position: relative;
top: 15px;
color: #888;
font-size: .75rem;
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
transform: rotate(270deg);
transform-origin: right top 0;
float:right;}
```